# How do you type a class decorator in typescript?

Tags: typescript

What would be the correct way to write a class decorator which accepts only specific classes?

I tried the following:

```
class Component {
  age: number;
}

function registerComponent(name: string) {
  return <T extends Component>(constructor: T): T => {
    return constructor as T;
  }
}

@registerComponent("demo")
class C1 extends Component {

}
```

Which results in:

```
Argument of type 'typeof C1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Property 'age' is missing in type 'typeof C1'.
```

[Try in TypeScript Repl](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0Afunction%20registerComponent(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E(constructor%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20constructor%20as%20T%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%40registerComponent(%22demo%22)%0Aclass%20C1%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What gets passed to the decorator is the type, not an instance of the type. Saying `constructor: T` means `constructor` must be an instance of type `T`, so instead you have to tell it that the parameter and the result are both constructors for the type `T`:

```
class Component {
  age: number;
}

function registerComponent(name: string) {
  return <T extends Component>(constructor: new () => T): new () => T => {
    return constructor;
  }
}

@registerComponent("demo")
class C1 extends Component {

}
```

and you would get an extra +1 for including the typescript repl if I could. Made it very easy to check my answer.

Note that you might also want to specify the constructor parameters.